# I can not download attachment from ssl with indy

Tags: ssl, indy

I have been using Indy for sending & receiving emails.Now I have a ssl mail server and I have not gotten attachments from email?
please help me....

```
Memo1.Clear;
POP3.ConnectTimeout := 20000;
if POP3.Connected then
  POP3.Disconnect;
POP3.Host := '*******';
POP3.Port := 995;
POP3.Username := '*******';
POP3.Password := '*******';
SSLIOHandler.Host := POP3.Host;
SSLIOHandler.Port := POP3.Port;
POP3.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
POP3.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS
try
  POP3.Connect;
except
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'Can not connect to server' + #13#10;
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + '==========' + #13#10;
end;
for i := 1 to POP3.CheckMessages do
begin
  Msg.Clear;
  POP3.RetrieveHeader(i, Msg)
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'Subject: ' + Msg.Subject + #13#10;
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'AttachmentCount: ' + IntToStr(Msg.MessageParts.AttachmentCount) + #13#10;
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'MessagePartsCount: ' + IntToStr(Msg.MessageParts.Count) +   #13#10;
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + '==========' + #13#10;
  for j := 0 to Msg.MessageParts.Count do
  begin
    if (Msg.MessageParts.Items[j] is TIdAttachmentFile) then
    begin
      //My Code
    end;
  end;
end;
POP3.Disconnect;
Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'End of conecction' + #13#10;
```

Answer (score 1):

SSL vs non-SSL has no effect whatsoever on Indy's ability to generate and parse emails.  If you are not getting any `TIdAttachment` objects in the `Msg.MessageParts` collection then either the emails are malformed in general, or the emails are using a format that Indy does not support.

Receiving or loading an email does not set the `AttachmentCount`, `RelatedPartCount`, or `TextPartCount` properties, so they will always be 0.  Those properties are only used when sending/saving an email, not when receiving/loading an email.  If you want those properties to have values when receiving/loading an email, you have to call the `Msg.MessageParts.CountParts()` method yourself, eg:

```
POP3.Retrieve(i, Msg);
Msg.MessageParts.CountParts;
Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'AttachmentCount: ' + IntToStr(Msg.MessageParts.AttachmentCount) + #13#10;
```

Lastly, keep in mind that if an email does not have any attachments, and is a simple plain-text email, or a single-part MIME email, then the `Msg.MessageParts` collection will not hold the email content, the `Msg.Body` property will instead.  The `Msg.MessageParts` property is only used for emails that contain multi-part and/or non-text data in it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you know any component that I can use it?

Comment: For what? Receiving an email? TIdPOP3 and TIdMessage work fine for that, you just have to use them correctly, that's all.

Comment: Then you are NOT using it correctly, but you have not explained WHY you can't get attachments or HOW you are trying to get them. Please show that additional code. I assure you, `TIdPOP3` and `TIdMessage` support attachments.

Comment: This is all of my code and I don't have additional code. If Msg.MessageParts.Count > 0 then I use `Msg.MessageParts.Items[i] is TIdAttachmentFile`. If you have better sample please write it thx.

Comment: Please update your original question with the attachment code you are actually using. I assume you are looping through the entire `MessageParts` collection, right? Also, try testing for `is TIdAttachment` generically instead of `is TIdAttachmentFile` specifically.

Comment: There are no attachments because you are calling `TIdPOP3.RetrieveHeader()`, which only downloads the email's top-level headers, not any body data, which includes attachments. You need to use `TIdPOP3.Retreive()` instead to download the email's body. With that said, your inner loop is exceeding the bounds of the `MessageParts` collection. Change `for j := 0 to Msg.MessageParts.Count do` to `for j := 0 to Msg.MessageParts.Count-1 do`. And you should change `is TIdAttachmentFile` to `is TIdAttachment` like I said earlier.

Comment: I have used 'TIdPOP3.Retreive()' but it does not work and Msg.MessageParts.Count again is 0. I saved my TIdMessage to a TMemoryStream and then save it to a txt file.I put this file for you maybe you can find my problem. (http://www.4shared.com/office/ErHGNgd3/TIdMessage_1.html)

Comment: I cannot download that file as I do not have a 4shared account and I am not going to create one just to download one file. But in any case, saving `TIdMessage` to a file is not the best way to diagnose this problem because it will have decoded the original data and encoded its own data to its own rules. I would need to see the original data from `TIdPOP3`. Either attach one of the `TIdLog...` components, like `TIdLogFile`, to the `TIdPOP3.Intercept` property, or use `TIdPOP3.RetrieveRaw()`, to get the raw email data that `TIdMessage` would be decoding.

Comment: BTW, you never said which version of Delphi and Indy 10 you are using.

Comment: Thnaks alot for your help. I save log in this link please see it [Logfile](http://www.upfordown.com/pupload/view/84245)

Comment: I use Delphi 2007 and Indy 10.1.5